# Android action bar icon missing

Tags: android, icons, action

I tried to add an icon to the Action Bar, in ShowAsAction I set it to ifRoom. But no matter how, the icon only shows up in the 3 dot menu and never show up in the Action Bar, what are the possible cause of this issue?

Comment: share the code you are using

Comment: Main Activity java https://gist.github.com/daQuincy/f38d697c15fe4682fa4b63b9c2dc8772  

menu_main.xml  
https://gist.github.com/daQuincy/8ff62af7e052d693a4465496812a3850

Comment: first thing , ICON NEVER GOES ANYWHERE ,so it's not missing :)  text your java file .

Comment: <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" 
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:orderInCategory="100" 
        app:showAsAction="always" />

Comment: If you have a label along with the icon, that can cause the menu item to be moved to the overflow menu. Try removing the label if its there.

Comment: @Radhey that's the weird part, changing it to always didn't work either, forgot to mention that

Comment: you can make it custom or replace it with toolbar.